# Error Code PINOT_UNABLE_TO_FIND_BROKER :No valid brokers found

Tags: presto, trino, apache-pinot, pinot

I am trying to query pinot table data using presto, below are my configuration details.

```
started Pinot is one of the sit server.i.e. 10.184.160.52
Controller: 10.184.160.52:9000
server: 10.184.160.52:7000
broker: 10.184.160.52:8000
```

I have Presto on different server Ports are open b/w these 2 servers. i.e.10.184.160.53

```
Created One pinot.properties file inside presto/etc/catalog/pinot.properties.

connector.name=pinot
pinot.controller-urls=Controller_Host:9000

bin/launcher run ---> Loaded Pinot catalog.
Started Prestro with Pinot Segment.

./presto --server 10.184.160.53:8080 --catalog pinot


show catalogs;(able to see my Catalog)
pinot

show schemas;  (able to see sachema also)
presto> show schemas;
   Schema       
--------------------
default 


presto> use default;
USE
presto:default> show tables;----(able to see pinot tables:)
    Table             
------------------------------
test                
test2 
test3                       
(3 rows)

Query 20210519_124218_00061_vcz4u, FINISHED, 1 node
Splits: 19 total, 19 done (100.00%)
0:00 [3 rows, 98B] [10 rows/s, 340B/s]
```

but when I am doing select * from test ; its showing broker not found

```
presto:default> select * from test;
Query 20210519_124230_00062_vcz4u failed: No valid brokers found for test
```

Complete Presto Logs:

```
Error Code  PINOT_UNABLE_TO_FIND_BROKER (84213767)
Stack Trace
io.prestosql.pinot.PinotException: No valid brokers found for test
at io.prestosql.pinot.client.PinotClient.getBrokerHost(PinotClient.java:285)
at io.prestosql.pinot.client.PinotClient.sendHttpGetToBrokerJson(PinotClient.java:185)
at io.prestosql.pinot.client.PinotClient.getRoutingTableForTable(PinotClient.java:302)
at io.prestosql.pinot.PinotSplitManager.generateSplitsForSegmentBasedScan(PinotSplitManager.java:72)
at io.prestosql.pinot.PinotSplitManager.getSplits(PinotSplitManager.java:167)
at io.prestosql.split.SplitManager.getSplits(SplitManager.java:87)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitScanAndFilter(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:203)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitTableScan(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:185)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner$Visitor.visitTableScan(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:156)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.plan.TableScanNode.accept(TableScanNode.java:143)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner.doPlan(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:124)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner.doPlan(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:131)
at io.prestosql.sql.planner.DistributedExecutionPlanner.plan(DistributedExecutionPlanner.java:101)
at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.planDistribution(SqlQueryExecution.java:470)
at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryExecution.start(SqlQueryExecution.java:386)
at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryManager.createQuery(SqlQueryManager.java:237)
at io.prestosql.dispatcher.LocalDispatchQuery.lambda$startExecution$7(LocalDispatchQuery.java:143)
at io.prestosql.$gen.Presto_350____20210519_105836_2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I am not able to understand what is happening here why this issue is showing for select statement.Looks like pinot broker is not accepting queries.someOne Kindly Suggest, What is the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This is because the connector does not support mixed case table names. Mixed case column names are supported. There is a pull request to add support for mixed case table names: https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/7630